# ForeignKey annotation doesn't seem to be working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following:

```
public class Sample
{
    public Person Sampler { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Sampler")]
    public int? Person_Id { get; set; }
}
```

but I keep getting error message "SqlException: Invalid column name 'Sampler'." when querying. I don't understand, since Sampler should not be a column when the sql is generated. Am I missing something here? This is something that always works for me although, admittedly the property name has been "Person" instead of "Sampler" in prior cases, so I am not sure what's going on.

Comment: Did you try reverse it? as in, set the `Person Sampler` property attribute: `[ForeignKey("Person_Id")]`?

Comment: the documentation says it's this way

Comment: ahh, i might have used a variant where we had to `[ForeignKey("Person_Id")] public virtual Person Sampler {get;set;}` once. Did you apply the virtual modifier? Sorry, cant remember anymore

Answer (score -2):

applying foreign key attribute on navigation property should work here

```
public class Sample{
public int SampleId{ get; set; }
public string SampleName{ get; set; }

public int? Person_Id { get; set; } 
[ForeignKey("Person_Id")]
public Person Sampler { get; set; } 
}
```

public class Person{

```
public int Person_Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public ICollection<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
}
```